# PDE: solving Fokker-Planck equation with initial and boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple

Here is the problem. We have the following simple PDE:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial t}= - a\frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial x} + \frac{D}{2} \frac{ \partial^2 p(x,t) }{\partial x^2}, \quad0<x<L, \quad t>0  
\end{equation} 
where $a$ and $D$ are constants.
We also  have the following initial and boundary conditions: 
\begin{equation}
p(x,0)=0\\
a p(x,t)- \frac{D}{2} \frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial x} = f(t) \quad at \quad x=0 \\
\frac{\partial^2 p(x,t)}{\partial x^2}=0 \quad at \quad x=L
\end{equation}

The expression, $\frac{\partial^2 p(x,t)}{\partial x^2}=0$, is not a standard well-known boundary condition and makes the PDE difficult to solve. I would be grateful if anyone have any idea for solving this PDE.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please write your equations in Mathematica format to increase the chances that readers will respond.  Substitute the second derivative boundary condition into the PDE to obtain a first order boundary condition and use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equations in the question can be written as

```
{D[p[x, t], t] + a D[p[x, t], x] - d/2 D[p[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0, 
 p[x, 0] == 0, 
 a p[0, t] - d/2 (D[p[x, t], x] /. x -> 0) - Sin[t] == 0, 
 D[p[xm, t], t] + a (D[p[x, t], x] /. x -> xm) == 0};
```

Unfortunately,

```
NDSolve[%, p, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, xm}]
```

returns unevaluated with the error message,

```
NDSolveValue::bdord: Boundary condition (p^(0,1))[1,t]+(p^(1,0))[1,t] should have derivatives of order lower than the differential order of the partial differential equation. >>
```

because the last boundary condition, above, contains a first derivative in time.  This situation has much in common with question [78493](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78493/pde-of-real-world-system-integral-boundary-condition), even though the equations are different.  Following that approach with (for example) `f = Sin[t]`, we decompose the PDE into a set of ODEs at `n` locations in `x`.

```
d = 1; a = 1; xm = 1;
n = 50; h = xm/n;
U[t_] = Table[u[i][t], {i, 0, n}];
eqns = Thread[D[U[t], t] == Join[
   {u[0][t] - Sin[t] - d/2 (u[1][t] - u[0][t])/h}, 
   -a ListCorrelate[{1, 0, -1}/(2 h), U[t]] + d/2 ListCorrelate[{1, -2, 1}/h^2, U[t]], 
   {-a (u[n][t] - u[n - 1][t])/h}]];
eqns = eqns /. eqns[[1, 1]] -> 0;
init = Delete[Thread[U[0] == 0], 1];
lines = NDSolve[{eqns, init}, U[t], {t, 0, 4 Pi}];
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Table[{i h, t, First[u[i][t] /. lines]}, {i, 0, n}]],
  {t, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "u"}, BoxRatios -> {1, 4, 1}]
```

[image]

Note that the array of equations, `eqns`, contains the boundary conditions,

```
eqns[[1]]
eqns[[n + 1]]
(* 0 == -Sin[t] + u[0][t] - 25 (-u[0][t] + u[1][t]) *)
(* Derivative[1][u[50]][t] == -50 (-u[49][t] + u[50][t]) *)
```

as well as `n - 1` equations representing the PDE itself, for instance,

```
eqns[[n/2]]
(* Derivative[1][u[24]][t] == -25 u[23][t] + 25 u[25][t] + 
   1/2 (2500 u[23][t] - 5000 u[24][t] + 2500 u[25][t]) *)
```

That such equations are readily solvable numerically suggests (to me, at least) that this capability should be added to `NDSolve`.